# View not filling the parent

Tags: android

I have an activity that contains a horizontal recycler view.
Now the main problem is I want to have a comment layout like the one in whats app which is at the bottom of the screen which is not filling the parent.

activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_mood_detail_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

row view of the recycler view:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_large"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/quote_image_mood_detail_activity"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />
            <include
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/layout_like_and_share"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                />
            <com.ascentbrezie.brezie.custom.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/comments_count_text_mood_detail_activity"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_small"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/display_comments_layout_mood_detail_activity"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_small"
                />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/abc"
                layout="@layout/layout_add_comments"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I use the above two codes I have the output as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZObZg.png)

But I want to set the edittext and the button at the button of the layout  as the footer,for that when I am using this layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_large"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/quote_image_mood_detail_activity"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />
            <include
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/layout_like_and_share"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                />
            <com.ascentbrezie.brezie.custom.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/comments_count_text_mood_detail_activity"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_small"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/display_comments_layout_mood_detail_activity"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_small"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        layout="@layout/layout_add_comments"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the problem is I get the XML preview exactly as I want. Have a look [here] but when I run the app on any device I get the output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNibr.png).

So the main problem is the footer layout doesn't stretch to fill up the parent and leaves some space to the right of the screen. I have dynamically set the margin for the whole of the view also.

RowLayout is the linear layout inside the scrollview. Card width is the width of the screen

```
rowLayout = (LinearLayout) holder.v.findViewById(R.id.row_layout);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(cardWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);
rowLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Why do you not add the margins in the layout file itself? Also try using `android:layout_weight=1` and set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for the controls you want to fill the parent.

Comment: The setting the layout width as 0dp and weight because I want the two items in the layout to distribute themselves as per the space available

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

`<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"><EditText android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/><Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button"/></LinearLayout>`